# Unable to remove seam in mesh

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, sculpting, edges, normals

I am having trouble getting rid of the seam in the ear I've made. I initially tried to drag in an ear I made using FaceBuilder, but decided to just make my own so I started over creating an ear from the mesh of the head.

I've tried recalculating normals,smoothing normals, deleting faces and remaking them completely again, joining meshes, and the union thing that you're supposed to do with the sculpt tool. I initially created the mesh for sculpting but didn't start sculpting with it and instead just made the ear in edit mode. So this issue popped up prior to doing any sculpting at all.

The only thing that worked at all is smoothing the normals which doesn't work anymore because I've now smoothed the vertices around the ear, which apparently messes it up.

[image: Back side of ear with distinct line]

[image: Side of ear with no seams]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by 3 or more faces that diverge from a single line segment, which creates infinitely paper thin geometry that can't really exist in the real world.

Here, I cut the head in half using a boolean modifier to help illustrate the issue. red indicating problematic spots that are causing the seams:

[image]

Here, I turned on face orientation (edit mode > overlays > face orientation) Blue indicates the front side of a face, red indicates the back side:

[image]

A fix would be to add thickness to those areas:

[image]

Comment: That was it! Thank you, I've been banging my head over this for hours.